# Popup Menu в настройках

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать всплывающее меню в настройках приложения таким вот образом:

```
popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), getView());
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_preference, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

Но не выходит, ошибки не выдает, но и меню тоже..
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: покажите как раздуваете фрагмент и где там слушатель относительно которого вы хотите вызвать popup, на данный момент ничего не ясно, такой код выше, может работать, всё зависит от того, что выше

Comment: Вот и мне не ясно. Хочу раздуть на пункте ListPreference, но как..